# Geoserver printProvider don't show comment/mapTitle with hebrew fonts

Tags: geoserver, printing

I have a printProvider running on my site.

```
 printProvider = Ext.create('GeoExt.data.MapfishPrintProvider', {
        method: "POST", 
        url: "http://xxxxx/geoserver/pdf",
        capabilities: printCapabilities, 
        customParams: {
            mapTitle: "הדגמה",
            comment: "This is a map printed from GeoExt."
        }
    });
```

When I try to print , the comment appears on the PDF but the mapTitle doesn't (hebrew fonts).

I there a way to fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved.
Need to add hebrew font and encoding utf-8 to the config.yaml

```
- !text
   text: "${mapTitle}"
   fontSize: 15 
   spacingAfter: 10                 
   font: Narkisim
   fontEncoding: Identity-H
   align: center
```